# Expected type specifier error gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following code:

In the file "Defs.h"

```
namespace ABCD
{
template < typename T >
class TPixelSum_TraitFor
{
    public:
        typedef double AccumType;
};


template <>
class TPixelSum_TraitFor< MonochromeImage::PixelType >
{
    public:
        typedef /*unsigned*/ long AccumType;
};
}
```

and in the file "GraphicLibrary.h"

```
#include "Defs.h"

using namespace ABCD;
using namespace std;

template < typename T, typename ACC_TRAIT = TPixelSum_TraitFor< T > > 
class SumImage : public TImageProcessor< T >
{
    public:

        typedef typename ACC_TRAIT::AccumType   AccumType;

    private:

        AccumType fSum;
};
```

and I get the following error

> expected type-specifier before ‘TPixelSum_TraitFor’
>
> expected ‘>’ before ‘TPixelSum_TraitFor’

at line

> template < typename T, typename ACC_TRAIT = TPixelSum_TraitFor< T > >

The code is compiled with g++ 4.8.1

Answer (score 2):

This code compiled with no errors under MSVC++ 11.0 U4. Only issue it was complaining about was undefined type specified as a base class:

```
TImageProcessor< T >
```

Are you sure this type is known in the scope of this file? I'm not fimiliar with GCC error messages, but this syntax:

```
template < typename T, typename ACC_TRAIT = TPixelSum_TraitFor< T > >
```

is perfectly valid, so he probably complains about next line.

UPDATE:

I tested your code with g++ 4.8.1.
I splitted content to two files and removed unknown types:

`test.h`:

```
namespace ABCD
{
  template < typename T >
  class TPixelSum_TraitFor
  {
  public:
    typedef double AccumType;
  };

  template <>
  class TPixelSum_TraitFor< long /*MonochromeImage::PixelType*/ > //MonochromeImage is unknown
  {
  public:
    typedef long AccumType;
  };
}
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

using namespace ABCD;
using namespace std;

template < typename T, typename ACC_TRAIT = TPixelSum_TraitFor< T > > 
class SumImage //: public TImageProcessor< T > -> TImageProcessor is also unknown
{
public:
   typedef typename ACC_TRAIT::AccumType   AccumType;

private:
  AccumType fSum;
};

int main()
{
}
```

Command:
`g++ -o test.o test.cpp`

Result: OK, no error.

Comment: It's probably due to unknown types commented out. I'm just guessing, though, GCC is something I am not very familiar with.

Comment: Well, we shouldn't be guessing, he should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can diagnose the problem. I also voted to close the question.